# I need help in ruby

Tags: ruby

1. I'm making a software but I don't want to publish it's source code right now because I don't want people to steal my hard work. I'm not rude or anything like that. Below is an example of what the program I'm making looks like.

> ```
> print "Username : "
> name = gets.chomp
>
>
> print "Password : "
> pass = gets.chomp
>
> if name =="user" and pass=="pa$$word"
> print "Hello"
>
> else print "Error, incorrect details"
> ```

Now this is a simplest login form in ruby but what bad happens here is whenever the user inserts wrong information the program will simply shutdown and what I want to happen is that I want to keep the program asking the user for right information until right information is inserted.

1. Are you a windows user? Do know how to program in batch files?
   examples

   echo Hello world
            cls

pause

So here is the code for ruby

```
a. print "Command : "
b. command = gets.chomp

c. if command == "Hello"

d. print "Hi, how are you?"

e. elsif command == "help"

f. print "Say hi to me, chat with me"
```

now what I want here too is just like in the first question

Details : After the user types in "Hi" the program just shuts down but what I want here it to make the program ask go to line a again

Comment: Needs a more descriptive title.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered my question. At last I found the solution myself :D

Comment: You can answer your own question so that people can vote on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the easy method :) If anyone is stuck with the problem I encountered all you do is this. The "while" loop

```
number = 1          # Value we will give for a string named "number" 
while number < 10   # The program will create a loop until the value 
                    # of the string named "number" will be greater than 10

    puts "hello"

                    # So what we need to do now is to end the loop otherwise
                    # it will continue on forever
                    # So how do we do it? 
                    # We will make the ruby run a script that will increase
                    # the string named "number"'s value every time we run the loop

    number = number + 1
end                 # Now what happens is every time we run the code all the program
                    # will do is print "hello" and add number 1 to the string "number". 
                    # It will continue to print out "hello" until the string is
                    # greater than 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop which continually asks for entry and checks the user's submission until a valid result is entered.

```
username = nil

while username.nil?
  puts "What is your username?"
  entered_username = gets.chomp

  if entered_username == "Bob"
    username = entered_username
  end
end

puts "Thanks!"
```

When run on the terminal this produces:

```
What is your username?
sdf
What is your username?
dsfsd
What is your username?
sdfsd
What is your username?
sdfds
What is your username?
sdf
What is your username?
Bob
Thanks!
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
until (print "Username : "; gets.chomp == "user") and
      (print "Password : "; gets.chomp == "pa$$word")
  puts "Error, incorrect details"
end
puts "Hello"
```

2.

```
loop do
  print "Command : "
  case gets.chomp
  when "Hello" then print "Hi, how are you?"; break
  when "help" then print "Say hi to me, chat with me"; break
  end
end
```